# Why cannt we use two script manager in the asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net page is having a script manger and i tried to added one more script manager.
it not accepting it
can some body help me why cant we have two script mangers in an ASP.NET page

Comment: Why you would like to have two if it works in one?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you only need one. Just stick it into your master page and it'll be fine.